# SSIS - how to access system variables in Script Task

Tags: variables, ssis

Can anyone please advice how to access/read system variables in Script Component (e.g I want to package name from this variable System::PackageName in Script Component)

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the Script Task Editor, provide the variable names you want to access (for example System::PackageName) in the ReadOnlyVariables field.

From the script, in the C# example, use this:

```
public void Main()
    {
        bool fireAgain = true;

        // Read the variable
        String PackageName = (String)Dts.Variables["System::PackageName"].Value;

        // Post the value to progress results
        Dts.Events.FireInformation(3, "Package name:", PackageName, "", 0, ref fireAgain);

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

The results:

[image: Package named Package]